# output of CIC filter is scaled by what frequency?

Tags: filters, comb

Suppose I have a CIC with a down sampling rate $R$, differential delay $M$, and number of sections $N$. My sample rate is $F_s$.

If I pass a signal through my CIC I will down sample by $R$. If I plot an FFT of the signal that passes through my CIC filter how should I scale the frequency?

My initial thought is that it should just be $F_s/R$ but this does not take into account the differential delay. Do the differential delay and or number of sections influence what I should be scaling the $F_s$ by?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like just $F_s$ is correct. See this link in the comments:

https://wirelesspi.com/cascaded-integrator-comb-cic-filters-a-staircase-of-dsp/

**Useful note for aliased signals :**
It is useful to note that the effective sampling frequency becomes $F_s$/$R$. You will see aliased artifacts if your input to the CIC is greater than ($F_s$/$R$)/2.